# [TextKit]Why some special characters could make Chinese characters thinner and smaller

Tags: ios, objective-c, textkit

That happens on TextKit. But everything is all right when I use CoreText.

[image: RichText with TextKit]

The rich text in the debug window of Xcode also has the same issue.

[image]

So, is it a bug of TextKit? Is there any solution in addition to replace TextKit by CoreText?

Comment: Some special unicode characters will cause the problem, such as ♬, ☜

Comment: I don't see a single special character in the picture you post.

Comment: @ElTomato ☜ is the special character in the case. The characters "啦啦啦啦" before ☜ are rendered correctly, but the characters after ☜ are rendered abnormally.

Comment: ☜ is not a special character.  It's a UNICODE symbol.  Most likely, the font family you have selected does cover it.  Anyway, your topic has little to do with programming.

Comment: Why the Chinese characters after ☜ are rendered thinner, but the same Chinese characters before ☜ are rendered correctly? @ElTomato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and the difference really exists between CoreText and TextKit. **I guess** it caused by the font fallback functions.

For example, we have a string "啦☜啦", and set a font. In case the given font don't have all characters, there usually a list of fallback fonts like:

```
English font
CJK font
Emoji font
Unicode font (support almost all the unicode character)
```

There are two ways to find a fallback font.

1. Find from beginning

   - Find '啦' in given font.
   - Not found, find in fallback fonts in order, found in CJK font.
   - Find '☜' in given font.
   - Not found, find in fallback fonts in order, found in Unicode font.
   - Find '啦' in given font.
   - Not found, find in fallback fonts in order, found in CJK font.
2. Find from previous

   - Find '啦' in given font.
   - Not found, find in fallback fonts in order, found in CJK font.
   - Find '☜' in **CJK font**.
   - Not found, find in fallback fonts in order, found in Unicode font.
   - Find '啦' in **Unicode font**
   - Found.

So if TextKit use the second way, two '啦's may use different fonts because of the character '☜'.

To solve this, you can use attributed string and give '☜' a different font size to break the fallback loop, then the second '啦' use CJK font.